# Permisos en tiempo de Ejecucion Android

Tags: android, programación-móvil, android-permissions

Tengo un problma, tengo una en donde muestro un Dialog personalizado, pero para este tipo de Dialog necesito de los permisos como este:

Pero para las nuevas versiones de android necesito pedir los permisos en tiempo de ejecucion, por lo que tome un ejemplo que habia hecho antes con la ubicacion, pero para este tipo de permiso no me funciona.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void accesoPermiso() {

    statusPermiso = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW);

    if (statusPermiso != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW},
                PERMISOALERTA);

    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {


    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISOALERTA:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //ubicarPorGps();
                //Aqui el Permiso es concedido
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso Denegado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

En el ejepmlo que habia hecho con localizacion me funciono de maravilla, pero al cambiar los permisos por SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, no me funciona y de una vez al iniciar la APP, de una vez salta al TOAST que dice permiso denegeado y no me muestra la ventana para solicitar el permiso.

Comment: Una pregunta tonta pero necesaria declaraste los permisos en el manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

Answer (score 0):

Si estas requiriendo manualmente el permiso [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)

Es importante que también sea definido dentro de tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```